# WHERE and CASE used together

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner  and  I'm having a hard time using `CASE` statements. Here I want to use a `CASE` if the condition (e.g. `segment = '87'` or `'30'`) is met. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

May I be missing something like a comma somewhere?

```
WITH status AS
(
  SELECT id,
  first_day AS 'month'
  WHERE segment = '87' CASE 
    WHEN subscription_start < first_day THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS is_active_87
  WHERE segment = '30' CASE 
    WHEN subscription_start < first_day THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS is_active_30
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is your `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not valid SQL; you need to include the condition you have in the `WHERE` into the `CASE` expression. Note you are also missing a `FROM` clause in your query:

```
WITH status AS
(
  SELECT id,
  first_day AS 'month',
  CASE WHEN segment = '87' AND subscription_start < first_day THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS is_active_87,
  CASE WHEN segment = '30' AND subscription_start < first_day THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS is_active_30
  FROM yourtable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite boolean expressions are evaluated as `0` for `FALSE` or `1` for `TRUE`, so there is no need for a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH status AS
(
  SELECT id,
    first_day AS month,
    (segment = '87' AND subscription_start < first_day) AS is_active_87,
    (segment = '30' AND subscription_start < first_day) AS is_active_30
  FROM tablename
)
```

Comment: It was for an exercise in an SQL course, so I was required to use CASE WHEN. But it's good to know that I can implement it without it. Thank you for the information!